# 同一セグメントの親機、中継器にそれぞれ別のSSIDを持たせることは可能ですか？

Tags: network

現在、2つ無線LANを設置していて、親機は`192.168.1.1`で、中継器は`192.168.11.1`で、それぞれ別のSSID(ESSID?)を持っています。

そして、親機を`192.168.1.1`に、中継器を`192.168.1.2`にしてそれぞれ別にSSIDを持たせ、親機に接続した子機と中継器に接続した子機を同一セグメントにしたいのですが、可能でしょうか？

追記: 
親機中継器共にbuffaloのWHR-G300NでファームウェアはOpenWRTです。
現在親機に接続した時の子機のIPアドレスは192.168.1.*,中継器の場合は192.168.11.*です。

Comment: 装置の仕様次第ですので、中継器の具体的な機種を書いてください。あと、親機と中継器、それぞれにぶら下がる端末にはどのようなIPアドレスになっているのでしょうか。(質問を編集して追記してください)

Answer (score 0):

BUFFALOの親機及び中継器を丁度いま設定してきたところですので、参考になるかどうか分かりませんが回答します。

光モデム―ルーター（192.168.100.1）―無線LAN親機（192.168.100.2）―中継器1（192.168.100.3）―中継器2（192.168.101.1）―中継器3（192.168.102.1）

上記接続経路にて、無線LAN親機からSSID：abcde_A（2.4GHz）とabcde_G（5GHz）の二つ電波が出ています。
中継器を設定する際に親機のどのSSIDを中継するか選択する画面がありますので、
abcde_Gを選択すると、中継器からはSSID:abcde_Gの電波が出ます。
従いまして、通常の方法では親機と中継器で別々のSSIDにはできないものと考えます。

余談ですが、中継器2と中継器3のセグメントが中継器1や親機と異なっているのは、
同一にした場合管理画面に入れなかった為このような設定になっています。
当方素人ですが、参考になれば幸いです。

上記回答をした後で調べてみましたが、
http://bbs.kakaku.com/bbs/K0000474768/SortID=16224685/
ここによると別のSSIDを設定できるようです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。しかし問題は「子機でルーティングをすることなく、つまりブリッジ接続で尚且つそれぞれ別のSSIDを割り振る」です。現在はL3接続で別のSSIDを割り振っています。